# Заряд или зарядка?

Tags: грамотная-речь, терминология

Как правильно называть то, на сколько ещё хватит аккумулятора телефона (ну или другого устройства): *зарядом* или *зарядкой?*

Когда я задумался об этом примерно полгода назад, то решил, что *заряд* более правильное слово, поскольку *зарядка* — это скорее сам процесс заряжания или в просторечии устройство для него.

Однако я нередко слышу, что употребляют именно последнее слово, говоря о том, на сколько ещё хватит телефона, например: *"Да у меня зарядки мало осталось, всего 15 %".*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Физика (справочный материал)**

Заряд – это физическое понятие. Существует элементарный электрический заряд, равный 1,6*10⁻¹⁹ кулонов – это заряд электрона.

Куло́н — единица измерения электрического заряда (количества электричества). Один кулон равен электрическому заряду, проходящему через поперечное сечение проводника с током силой в 1 А за время 1 с

Но какое отношение это имеет к ёмкости аккумулятора в телефоне?

**Ёмкость аккумулятора** — это **заряд**, отдаваемый полностью заряженным аккумулятором при разряде до наименьшего допустимого напряжения. В системе СИ ёмкость аккумуляторов измеряют в кулонах, на практике часто используется внесистемная единица — ампер-час.

Ёмкость аккумуляторов измеряется в миллиампер-часах. mA∙h, мА∙ч – сокращение от миллиампер-час. Это производная от другой единицы (ампер-час) и используется **для измерения ёмкости аккумуляторов,** используемых для работы ноутбуков, мобильных телефонов, планшетов.

**2. Лингвистика (словари)**

**ЗАРЯДИТЬ,** 4. что. Придать чему-л. какую-л. электрическую энергию, поляризовать в чём-л. частицы. З. аккумуляторы, электрическую батарею.

**ЗАРЯД,** м. 1. к Зарядить – заряжать. Произвести заряд аккумуляторов, электрических приборов. ДЕЙСТВИЕ
4. Об электрической энергии, содержащейся в чём-л. Электрический з. Измерить з. У батарейки кончился з. КОЛИЧЕСТВО ЭЛЕКТРИЧЕСТВА

**ЗАРЯДКА;** ж. 1. к Зарядить – заряжать (1.З.) и Зарядиться - заряжаться. З. ружья. З. аккумулятора.

**3. Вывод: как правильнее?**

Емкость аккумулятора в телефоне и компьютере – это **величина заряда, определяющая нормальную работу устройства** (от максимально возможного до предельно допустимого значения), и информация об этом состоянии приводится **в  процентах.**

Поэтому **заряд** в аккумуляторе – это скорее **общее понятие** о количестве накопленного электричества в нем, а вот **зарядка – это уровень заполнения аккумулятора электричеством,** и это именно та тема, которая нас интересует.

Поэтому  в современных словарях уже отмечается это значение (словарь Ефремовой),  и оно становится всё более употребительным, **имея на это все основания.**

---

**Комментарий и вариант второго ответа**

Вот вы пишете: «я согласен [...], что ёмкость величина постоянная, хотя может со временем падать, это не тот параметр, измеряемый в процентах, о котором я спрашивал».

Но кто же спорит? Конечно, **ёмкость – это величина постоянная.** Давайте рассмотрим простую аналогию: вот **современный электрический чайник.** У него есть постоянная ёмкость, и, в отличие от электрической ёмкости, она даже не падает со временем. Мы наливаем в чайник воду, причем есть указатели минимального и максимального уровня заполнения: максимальный уровень – это 100℅, а минимальный уровень – это 0℅.

Всё как **в нашем телефоне,** в котором тоже есть **постоянная ёмкость аккумулятора и два крайних уровня ее заполнения.** Другие уровни также обозначены, но уже в процентах. Эти уровни соответствуют напряжению для нормальной работы устройства. Вот только «наливаем» мы в аккумулятор **не воду, а элементарные электрические заряды, которые измеряются в кулонах.** Ёмкость аккумулятора тоже измеряется в кулонах, это просто определенное количество этих зарядов (соответствие с нашим примером прямое – кулоны и литры).

Хотя в системе СИ ёмкость аккумуляторов измеряют в кулонах, на практике часто используется **внесистемная единица** — ампер-час и **миллиампер-час** (mA∙h, мА∙ч). В наших телефонах ёмкость, вероятно, указана в паспорте именно в mA∙h, мА∙ч. Проверьте на всякий случай. Но на самом деле это **те же кулоны, то есть электрический заряд в чистом виде.**

**Так что же мы измеряем в процентах?** Мы измеряем **относительную заполненность наших аккумуляторов электрическими зарядами.** Это те же кулоны, только в относительной величине. Телефон заряжен на 50℅ электрическими зарядами, как чайник залит водой наполовину.

**Как же лучше сказать: заряд или зарядка?**

У меня заряда (дословно – электрических зарядов) мало осталось, всего 15 %. Звучит немного **претенциозно**, ведь это не специализированная речь физиков, а бытовая ситуация, и измеряем мы этот заряд не в кулонах, а в относительных единицах, что уже нарушает точность академической речи.

**Заряд** – многозначное слово, в том числе это основная единица в международной системе СИ. И совсем неплохо, если по семантике мы **уйдем от точного физического понятия и будем ближе к определенному процессу.** Действительно, зарядка – это процесс, но в языке полученный результат часто называют тем же словом, и это фиксируется словарями, это нормальное явление.

Понаблюдайте за речью окружающих, какой вариант покажется вам **более частотным.** Я, к примеру, с трудом представляю, чтобы современный ребенок говорил «у меня заряд на компьютере закончился».

**Спасибо за внимание, если дочитали до конца.**

Comment: Вам спасибо большое! Почему зря? Очень полезно это было мне! Тем более я проголосовал за оба ваших ответа и принимаю этот.

Comment: А если я поддержал вашего оппонента, это совсем не значило, что всё остальное мне не понравилось и было впустую. Как раз наоборот! ;) А лучше **этого последнего** ответа и быть не может.))

Comment: Спасибо, Артем, мы всегда будем друзьями. Меня тут хорошо и очень оперативно отредактировали, но вы ведь вы уже все прочитали, а оставлять лишнюю информацию действительно ни к чему

Comment: Ну да, удачно успел всё прочитать в начальном виде и не успел запутаться. :)

Answer (score 2):

Строго говоря - и то, и другое неверно. Чисто "по науке" - надо бы "остаток энергии", но так мало кто говорит, разве что какой-то уж очень рафинированный физик-теоретик.

Тут такая тонкость, что заряд - это понятие статическое. Его нельзя расходовать. Уровень заряда - еще туда-сюда, но "остаток заряда" - это неверно с технической точки зрения.
А вот "зарядка" (в одном из значений) это как раз величина динамическая (в бытовом понимании слова "динамика"). И она, таким образом, может меняться.

> ЗАРЯДКА, -и; ж. 1. к Зарядить - заряжать (1.З.) и Зарядиться -
> заряжаться. З. ружья. З. аккумулятора. Получить творческую зарядку.
> Получить зарядку бодрости.
> (БТС)

Хотя тут нет примера на электричество, но это то самое значение. Если "зарядку" (а не только заряд) "бодрости" можно получить, то почему нельзя получить - а потом расходовать - "зарядку аккумулятора"?
Тут натяжка на натяжке в такой логике, но всё-таки это, как ни странно, ближе в физическому смыслу.

Для автомобильных аккумуляторов привычны термины емкость (текущая) и полная емкость (максимальная). Но в силу, видимо, другой сути процесса термины не прижились для аккумуляторов современных девайсов.

В такой ситуации можно ожидать, что слово "зарядка" со временем разовьёт еще одно, подходящее к случаю значение. Но пока я бы советовал избегать использования обоих сочетаний вне подчеркнуто разговорного контекста.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119669/discussion-on-answer-by-behemothus---).

Answer (score 1):

по Ожегову:
ЗАРЯД, -а, м. 1. Количество взрывчатого вещества, необходимое длявзрыва, выстрела и содержащееся в соответствующем устройстве в специальномвместилище. 3. взрывчатки. Пороховой з. 3. энергии (также перен.: о скопившейся в ком-н. энергии). *2. Количество электричества, содержащееся в данном теле.* Электрический з. (величина, определяющая интенсивность электромагнитного взаимодействия заряженных частиц). Снежный заряд - внезапный и сильный снегопад.

ЗАРЯДИТЬСЯ, -яжусь, -ядишься и -ядишься; сов. 1. (1 и 2 л. не употр.). Стать заряженным. 2. перен. Приобрести нек-рый запас энергии, подбодрить себя чем-н. (разг.). 3. на дорогу. II несов. заряжаться, -аюсь, -аешься. 1) сущ. зарадка, -и, ж.

ЗАРЯДКА, -и; ж. 1. к Зарядить - заряжать (1.З.) и Зарядиться - заряжаться. З. ружья. З. аккумулятора.

Итак, заряд аккумулятора - количество. Полный заряд, ползаряда, 20% заряда.
Зарядка - процесс (заряжание)или устройство для заряжания (неологизм).

Answer (score 0):

Правильно говорить *осталось **разрядки**,* гыгы, или ***ёмкости** аккумулятора,* которая измеряется в ампер-часах, то есть заряд·время: "Заряженный аккумулятор с заявленной ёмкостью в 1 А·ч теоретически способен обеспечить силу тока в один ампер на протяжении одного часа" (цитата из Вики, но не принципиально, суть передана). То есть оценивается процесс разрядки заряженного элемента, а не его "заряд" и тем более не "зарядка".

Ну и если уж совсем корректно, то **осталось 30% от максимальной ёмкости аккумулятора** (или другой батареи).

Ёмкость в электрофизике это *capacity (A battery's capacity is the amount of electric charge it can deliver at the rated voltage.* Wiki). Стандартизация терминологии - это наше всё.

Но в быту допустимо хоть просто сказать: **у меня 30% аккумулятора**.

Вообще, в быту никто не выражается физическими терминами и даже массу, ту что в килограммах, везде называют весом.